# android xml - how to overlap two view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an image like one below,there is two view represented by dark green and green.how to make green above dark green,because as we can see part of the dark green area is covered by green ?

[image]

and this my simple code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:background="@color/dark_green">
</View>
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
    android:background="@color/green">
</View>
```

Comment: Use `FrameLayout` as parent of both views

Answer (score 0):

Use Relativelayout as parent layout and it will work file

```
 <Relativelayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">
<View
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
android:background="@color/dark_green">
</View>
<View
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
android:background="@color/green">
 </View>
 </Relativelayout >
```

Comment: I don't see any change

Comment: Just interchange the view and than check